# Article classification in given categories using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am very new python and machine learning, I have some predefined categories or tag set like this `[cricket, football, politics, education, movie]` etc. now I want to identify given article is which categories I tried to count words of given article and matched with most occurrence of words count in given categories like bags of words.

But BOW ( Bags Of Word ) not solve my problem for example consider this following example of article:

`article 1: " BCCI nominate Ravi Shatri name as Indian coach "
 article 2: " Sachin Tendulakar is a member of Rajya Sabha "`

In above this two article first article fitted to `Cricket` categories and second article fitted to `Politics` categories but with the BOW this article not fitted in any of give categories.

My question is how to solve this article classification problem, which algorithm is best suite for this. Any help is highly appreciate.

Comment: Some methods that might be useful for you would be nearest neighbor, SVM or neural networks. But it depends on the complexity of the problem and the amount of training data which method you should choose

Answer (score 1):

Collect data for cricket, football, politics, education, movie related articles. Then the data set will be paragraphs, and they belong to one of the category as mentioned above.

Now train a classifier that given a article can predict which category this article belong to. You can start with simplest Bag of word representation of articles for classification then analyse the results and accuracy. After that can move forward to more sophisticate approach like word to vector or document to vector for word representation and then train a classifier.

After making classification model, for assigning category to your test document you need to clasify it using classification model.